# "In countries where X" or "In countries which X"?

Tags: relative-pronouns, ielts

I am preparing for IELTS using the following book, "CAMBRIDGE Action Plan for IELTS". On page 75 of the text, there is a sentence

> "In countries ***where*** water seems to be readily available, people may, at first, be reluctant to reduce their water consumption".

My question is why the relative pronoun ***where***, not *which* is used in the sentence.

I thought the relative pronoun should be *which* because in the sentence there is "in" at the beginning of it and, as far as I know, the relative pronoun *where* is equal to *in/at/on which*.

Answer (score 4):

There are in effect two *in*s in this sentence.

The first *in* tells where people are reluctant:

> *In countries* ...

The second *in* tells which countries:

> ... countries *in which* water seems to be readily available ...

Put them together and you get

> In countries in which water seems to be readily available ...

But *where* can substitute for a locative preposition phrase like *in which*:

> In countries where water seems to be readily available ...